# Date compare and value changes

Tags: sql, date, conditional-statements

I have a probable easy question for someone.
I need to compare two existing date values in SQL, fields A, and B. After I compare them, I need to add a condition that says, if field A is 30 days greater than field B, you should change the status in field C to some value. This should be executed every day.

I have an issue with comparing and setting condition. Trying to find the solution on overflow but didn't get the info that I need. All fields are in the same table.

I was trying something like basic update but then I've got thing in my mind that I should probable use function.

Maybe if you can provide me code for this case, it will be great!

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and date/time function are quite vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:-**

```
update table set C = <value> where DATEDIFF(d,B,A) > 30
```

Answer (score 0):

By this, I've managed to come to my solution.
In an addition, I had to use the try_Convert function to get the exact date type for calculation!

Thank you!